# Insert statement with primary key and scope identity

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008, pdo

I want to get the the primary key (auto_increment) for the latest record to use it as a foreign key in the other table. When I use the SCOPE_IDENTITY() as a pdo parameter, I get the error:

> Call to undefined function SCOPE_IDENTITY().

When I use it as a direct value, the statement always rolls back.

Is my code correct?

```
if (empty($errors)) {
    $sqlconnection = new SqlConnection();

    $conn = $sqlconnection->db_connect();

    if ($conn) {
        if (sqlsrv_begin_transaction($conn) === false ) {
            $errors[] = "Cant start transaction.";
        } else {
            // Query1
            $query1 = "INSERT INTO [RC.table1] (terminname, datum) VALUES (?, ?)";
            $params1 = array($eventname, $eventdate);
            $stmt1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query1, $params1);

            //Query2
            $query2 = "INSERT INTO [RC.table2] (appointment_id, mandant_id) VALUES ((SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()), ?)";
            $params2 = array($_SESSION['mandant_id']);
            $stmt2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query2, $params2);

            if($stmt1 && $stmt2) {
                 sqlsrv_commit( $conn );
                 echo "Transaction committed.<br />";
            } else {
                 sqlsrv_rollback( $conn );
                 echo "Transaction rolled back.<br />";
            }
        }
    } else {
        $errors[] = "Cant connect to database.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using @@IDENTITY instead

Comment: @Sparky: Using `@@IDENTITY` is not recommended if there's a trigger on the table you're inserting into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution: replace

```
    $query2 = "INSERT INTO [RC.table2] (appointment_id, mandant_id) VALUES ((SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()), ?)";
```

with this:

```
    $query2 = "DECLARE @LastID INT; SET @LastID = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); INSERT INTO [RC.table2] (appointment_id, mandant_id) VALUES (@LastID, ?)";
```

Also, for `@LastID` variable definition (`DECLARE @LastID INT`) please use the same data type as data type of `appointment_id` column. In this example, I assumed that `@LastID`'s type is `INT`.

**Edit:** You could create the following [stored procedure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) with [TRY ... CATCH](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Insert_Table1Table2 
(
    @terminname NVARCHAR(50), 
    @datum DATE,
    @mandant_id INT 
)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO [RC.table1] (terminname, datum) VALUES (@terminname, @datum)
        DECLARE @appointment_id INT; 
        SET @appointment_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); 
        INSERT INTO [RC.table2] (appointment_id, mandant_id) VALUES (@appointment_id, @mandant_id)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(2048);
        SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();
        RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, 16, 1)

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```

Note: You should replace every type and max. length with the proper type and length.

Comment: also rollback. Is it a correct solution, when I reading the latest id from the table and add +1 and using this for the id?

Comment: No. Why don't use a stored procedure ? I would use a stored procedure to execute these INSERTs.

Comment: can I call a stored procedure with parameters? I have a session variable for the second insert.

Comment: @mnlfischer: See **Edit 1**.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRAN T1;
INSERT INTO [RC.table1] (terminname, datum) VALUES ('alibaba', '24.02.2014');
BEGIN TRAN T22
INSERT INTO [RC.table2] (appointment_id, mandant_id) VALUES ((SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()), '0200')
COMMIT TRAN T1;
COMMIT TRAN T2;
```

that works perfectly in the studio. dont know, why I cant get the identity in the php transaction.

Comment: why don't you use `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in the second query of your question?

Comment: Is the code in your question really doing this? Where does it actually `BEGIN TRAN T1;` and `BEGIN TRAN T22`?

Answer (score -1):

By the way, while that code MIGHT work, I would suggest the following changes...

```
   $query1 = "INSERT INTO [RC.table1] (terminname, datum) VALUES (?, ?);select @@identy"
```

now, retrieve the result (which will be the new key added) and pass it as a parameter to the next SQL call.